# Spark df not selecting nested fields as column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a Spark df which contains both top level and nested fields from a list of dictionaries containing key and values which correspond to key and value of a json object and I am having issues with selecting nested columns.

Here is what I have so far:

Input is a list of dictionaries containing JSON values:

```
[{
  "uid": 98763,
  "estimatedGrade": {
    "science": 10.03,
    "english": 20.5,
   },
  "actualGrade":  {
    "science": 10.03,
    "english": 20.5,
   }
}]

printed schema:
 |-- uid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- actualGrade: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- science: double(nullable = true)
 |    |-- english: double (nullable = true)
 |-- estimatedGrade: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- science: double(nullable = true)
 |    |-- english: double (nullable = true)
```

desired output:

| uid | estm.science | estm.english | act.science | estGrade.english |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val | val | val | val | val |

*please note I don't need to renamed the column but had to shorten them to fit in one line

This is my code so far:

```
    #jsons contains list of dict with the json key/values
    df = self._spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsons).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
    df = self._spark.read.json(df, multiLine=True)
    
    logger.info("Df count: %s", df.count())
    logger.info("Df table schema: %s", df.printSchema())
    
    columns = ['uid', 'estimatedGrade.science', 'estimatedGrade.english', 'actualGrade.science', 'actualGrade.english']
    
    df.select([column_header for column_header in df.columns if column_header in columns])
```

I am able to select only uid which is top level field so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with selecting nested value.

Please help.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It's not possible to test your code fragment that is not runnable.

Answer (score 0):

The **df.columns** only returns top-level column names. You can check this by running it on the df created using the data sample you provided. It returns: `['actualGrade', 'estimatedGrade', 'uid']`.

Only good way I know of at this point is to iterate over the df.schema. Recursively, if the field is of StructType, then check the field's nested columns.

Here's some code which should help you on your way.
First, import StructType

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
```

Then, set up some helper functions. The first one is for recursively returning all the column names, including nested columns using dot-notation.
The second helper function flattens the list.

```
def get_schema_field_name(field, parent=None):
  if type(field.dataType) == StructType:
    if parent == None:
      prt = field.name
    else:
      prt = parent+"."+field.name # using dot notation
    res = []
    for i in field.dataType.fields:
      res.append(get_schema_field_name(i, prt))
    return res
  else:
    if parent==None:
      res = field.name
    else:
      res = parent+"."+field.name
    return res

def flatten(S):
  if S == []:
    return S
  if isinstance(S[0], list):
    return flatten(S[0]) + flatten(S[1:])
  return S[:1] + flatten(S[1:])
```

Then, loop over your schema and get all the columns (including nested ones) using the methods from above.

```
column_list = []
for j in df.schema:
  column_list.append(get_schema_field_name(j))
column_list = flatten(column_list)
```

Finally, replace the df.columns part in your select statement.

```
columns = ['uid', 'estimatedGrade.science', 'estimatedGrade.english', 'actualGrade.science', 'actualGrade.english']

df.select([column_header for column_header in column_list if column_header in columns])
```

Worked when testing on Databricks 8.2 (Spark 3.1.1).

[image: From Databricks]

I've also used this approach for listing all column names in all tables in Spark, so feel free to check the article for further reference: https://medium.com/helmes-people/how-to-view-all-databases-tables-and-columns-in-databricks-9683b12fee10